# screenupdating with activeworkbook code

Tags: vba, excel

If I have code that starts with screenupdating = false, and then later in the code it defines a workbook through ActiveWorkbook, will the screenupdating = false affect what is considered to be the activeworkbook?

Answer (score 3):

`.ScreenUpdating` is applied on the Application Object and not on top-level objects inside Excel. This means that the property will be applied to the whole of Excel including any new workbook. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The workbook that you are working in is still the `ActiveWorkbook`. `Screenupdating = False` just makes it where you don't see what is going on when you run some VBA/Macro code. It makes it more efficient time wise, because less memory and processor power are used because the GUI of Excel won't be moving around, changing, etc.